# How to migrate roles from one apache ranger instance to other instance?

Tags: apache-ranger, cloudera-cdp

We are planning to make a replica cluster of existing CDP cluster. I can import/export policies but can not import/export roles.

We have around 2k+ roles, using following api I can create role but wanted to know if this can be automated

```
/public/v2/api/roles
```

Any pointers would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no easy our automated way to import/export roles in Ranger-CDP.
However, we can automate it using a simple python script. You can find the script on following url:-

```
https://github.com/patilajinkya/ranger_automate/blob/main/roles_exporter.py
```

Note:- Please read `roles_exportes_README.txt` before executing the script and let me know if you face any issues. I have tested this on one my test clusters and all looks good.

One thing to keep in mind is, all users and groups from source cluster needs to be available in destination cluster and no duplicate roles should exist in destination cluster.

If you have any suggestions to improve the script, let me know in the comments.

Comment: @potatoaim, please run this script on python 2.7. It can be run on a host from which both the ranger instances are accessible.

Comment: From code looks like, the script gonna generate the console output. Which is fine, I can redirect to a file but having it to redirect to a file as well would helpful.